# Magento product csv upload with images

Tags: magento, csv

I’m trying to upload the csv file with about 300 products in and I’m having a couple of issues with it. 
1). I have put the images in media/catalog/product/images/ and the path I’m giving in csv is /images/image_name.jpg. Now when I import the csv I can see the products with image at frontend. But in admin panel, I can’t see any image against the products. I don’t know where I’m doing wrong to show these images in admin panel. 
2). I have a couple of multi select attributes. CSV import is not working with multi select attributes (it just picks up the first one). Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are placing your images to wrong folder and they should be in `media/import` instead with right permissions and case sensitive names.

Refer to http://blog.calientedesign.com/?p=56 or perform a web search for "magento image import"

Comment: I have been trying exactly the same for last 2 days but no luck. I have put my images in media/import folder and made sure the images names are the same (since I am trying it on localhost so permission is not an issue). When I import the csv, it uploaded the products and show them at front-end but in admin panel, when I look into the "Images" tab under Manage products, it shows no image.

Comment: localhost or not file permissions do matter

Answer (score 1):

As Jonathan said, you must put all of your images that you wish to import into media/import.  The other crucial part of this is your CSV.  Every image name must of course match properly, but it must have a forward slash in front of the image name.  So, if you put 'image1.jpg' into media/import, then in your spreadsheet, the image columns should have '/image1.jpg'.

Comment: Thats what I have done but as I said I can see the images at frontend but admin it says no image.